# Broswers only working for some websites

Tags: google-chrome, browser

My two browsers,Chrome and Mozilla, will only open some websites. I can't even use Google.

On Mozilla, it shows

[image]

Whereas in Chrome, it shows

[image]

Comment: it's good to have a second router to try

Comment: okay, this worked. Thank you so much. I don't know why I didn't try this before. But can you explain why this worked and what I can do with the previous router where this had an issue? The previous router was a hotspot from a smartphone. It used to work before but suddenly my problem happened. The hotspot's security is WPA2 PSK and AP band is 5GHz band

Comment: if from the phone you can access those websites normally then it seems like maybe it has to be the wireless hotspot app that is an issue, you could try a different wireless hotspot app.

Comment: also sometimes things aren't really designed for us to find out where the problem really is!! and the best we can do is try to isolate the problem and change things